# How to fork a local git repository in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, git-fork

I have a solution / project in Visual studio 2019.
Using the git functions in VS I have created a local only repository.
( for various reasons I will not create a remote repo for this solution / project )

How can I fork the solution to a new local repo, forking all branches ?

Fork, not clone.

Many thanks for your help on this one

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fork the solution to a new local repo, forking all branches ?

Just clone it.

You're probably misunderstanding something, because in most cases you don't want to create local clones.

> Fork, not clone.

A fork is pretty much a clone.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but ... as far as I understand ... A clone causes the new repo to continue to have a relationship / link to the original repo, while a fork fully separates them ?   Again, many Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Git there is no such thing as a "fork" or a "clone". You can make a copy of your repository by just copying the folder. There is an operation called `git clone`, which essentially does that. The only "relationship" between repositories (ignoring advanced features) is the list of remotes, but you can add them or remove them at will.

Comment: Im not an expert on Github but im pretty sure a simple clone and a fork is not necessarily the same thing. I think there is an "fork" button on every project, which will create the "fork", a copy of the project into your own github space. That repo you can then clone and start developing (and create pull requests to merge changes to the original repo). However, im not an expert and maybe someone that has more knowledge could elaborate